# Playframework 2.2: IllegalStateException: No value when invoking bindFromRequest

Tags: java, playframework

In Playframework 2.2.x, I got this error when I was trying to binding form data to pojo.

```
IllegalStateException: No value
```

And here is my sample code:

```
Form<OrderRequest> form = new Form<OrderRequest>(OrderRequest.class);
final OrderRequest orderRequest = form.bindFromRequest().get();
```

This article is meant to leave the trail for people who suffer similar problem.

I will answer it myself later.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what caused this problem so I decided to find out which parameter that might trigger this problem.

Here is structure of OrderRequest:

```
public class OrderRequest {
  private int num;
  private boolean isAdmin;
  private String name;

  ....

}
```

I was able to narrow it down to two parameters, it turned out when the input parameter **[num]** was null, it doesn't recognize null as type **int**, so is parameter **[isAdmin]** as its type **boolean**, **for these are primitive data type, are not nullable type.**

To avoid this situation, I suggest that always checks the type of each parameter, making sure the setting value matches type.

**As mentioned, primitive data type are not nullable type.**

One thing you could do is replacing primitive data type to [wrapper class](http://goo.gl/HrxeK2), it will fix this problem.

```
public class OrderRequest {
  private Integer num;
  private Boolean isAdmin;
  private String name;

  ....

}
```